# python card game track winners

Tags: python

Hi guys I just started learning python and come across a problem:
I am writing a code for an card game, Whistful Hearts.
In this game there are 13 rounds and 4 players, in each around each player plays a card and the play with highest card wins, and the winner lead the next round.
so if the order for first round is 1234 and the cards played are [2,3,10,A] 
So player 4 wins the first round, the order for next round will be 4123 and cards played are [5,1,8,Q]. I am just wondering how can I keep track which card is played by which player, like in second round player 4 played 5, player 1 played 1...etc, and also the order of each round, who played first, second ... etc.
I so sorry if its not clear enough :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list of tuples with the first element of each tuple the player number and the second the card played, e.g.

```
round1 = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 10), (4, 'A')]
round2 = [(4, 5), (1, 1), (2, 8), (3, 'Q')]
```

You would then have a list of rounds to represent the 13 rounds for a game:

```
rounds = [[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 10), (4, 'A')],
          [(4, 5), (1, 1), (2, 8), (3, 'Q')],
          ...
          [(3, 2), (4, 10), (1, 'K'), (2, 'J')]
```

It is also possible to record just the player number that led each round because, assuming that play always proceeds in the same direction, the remaining players can be derived from the first . You could implement this with a custom class, a named tuple, or even by storing the lead player in the first element of each round list, but I think that this makes is a little more complicated than it needs to be.

P.S. there is no `1` card in a standard deck.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to do `player_list = [1, 2, 3, 4] * 2`, then `for player in player_list[starting_player_idx : starting_player_idx+4]: play()`

Comment: @AdamSmith: perhaps. Perhaps you should flesh that out and add it as an answer?

Comment: no I think that goes beyond what the question is asking. OP seems to need to know how to store the historical data, which your answer does a great job of presenting. He never asks how to get a list of players for the round!